# Post build event through a .prop file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am searching for a way to set a VS2010 project post build event through a .prop file.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <_ProjectFileVersion>10.0.30319.1</_ProjectFileVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>
      <Command>copy "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)$(PlatformArchitecture)\"</Command>
    </PostBuildEvent>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Yes - a lot of it is just boilerplate that needs to be there to make any property sheet work in Visual Studio.  After the XML declaration line (line 1) we define a Project node, which contains an ItemDefinitionGroup node, which contains our PostBuildEvent node.  The contents of the nested Command node contains the command we wish to run after the build completes.  In the above example it simply copies the build target ($(TargetPath) in Microsoft speak) to a subfolder under the solution directory -something like "mysolution/Debug64" if you are building in Debug and have the platform set to x64.